# Non-generic IEnumerable to string

Tags: c#

There are a lot of questions/answers about conversion from **generic** IEnumerable to a string.

But I need a conversion from a **non-generic** *IEnumerable* to a *string*. The result string should be in form of
 `element1.ToString() + ", " + element2.ToString() + ", " + element3.ToString() + ...`
Is there a shorter way than using *StringBuilder* and looping through the elements by *MoveNext()*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still use LINQ:

```
String.Join(", ", thingy.Cast<object>());
```

Comment: Thanks. But this causes a **compile error** "Argument type 'IEnumerable<object>' is not assignable to parameter type 'string[]'". My fix is `string.Join(", ", thingy.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray())`. Is there a shorter way?

Comment: You might not need the `.ToArray()`, depending on what parameters your version of .NET accepts.  Otherwise, that looks good.

Comment: @SLaks answer is correct for .NET 4.0. I just tried it. .NET 3.5 needs: `string.Join(", ", thingy.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray())`.